# Length of goo.gl URL's

Tags: url-shortener, goo.gl

I'm using the goo.gl link shortener API in my app to send urls to twitter along with a link. I've been allowing users to submit 119 characters, appending a space, and then the URL because I was under the impression that they were always 19 characters. This should leave me with one to spare.

Unfortunately I've been getting some "tweet is too long" errors and I can't seem to find any documentation about the possible range of goo.gl url lengths. Does anyone know what the max is or know where some reliable documentation on it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter now automatically shortens all links by itself, using `t.co`. Don't do it by yourself.

Read: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq#How_do_I_calculate_if_a_Tweet_with_a_link_is_going_to_be_over_140_characters_or_not

> If you are not using the opt-in features, only links shorter in length
>   than a t.co URL will be wrapped by t.co. All links t.co-length or
>   longer should be considered as t.co's maximum length. For example, if
>   help/configuration reports 20 characters as the maximum length, and a
>   user posts a link that is 125 characters long, it should be considered
>   as 20 characters long instead. If they post a link that is 18
>   characters long, it's still only 18 characters long.

At the moment `short_url_length` is equal `22` (https://api.twitter.com/1/help/configuration.json)

Comment: Does not really answer my question, which was what is the goo.gl maximum. That's precisely why I use goo.gl, originally it was 19 characters which frees up those extra 3 for my users. It also was not variable, so I didn't have to check whenever I wanted to use it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use goo.gl or not - Twitter will shorten goo.gl link to t.co as well.

Comment: Hey John, I owe you an apology. You were right. According to Twitter:

"As of October 10, 2011 the t.co URL wrapper automatically wraps all links submitted to Twitter, regardless of length. This includes so-called URLs without protocols."

So while my goo.gl urls might still show up in the tweets themselves, behind the scenes a t.co wrapper is put in place and counted towards the character total. This seems like a poor development choice to me, but it is what it is. 

Again, sorry for being rude in my last comment. Turns out you were right.